# Сокращение кода при написании бота на pyTelegramBotAPI (решение)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

За год я написал где-то 10 Telegram ботов на библиотеке **pyTelegramBotAPI** и все они вкратце выглядят так:

```
import logging
import time

import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import Message

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='errors.txt',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='\n%(asctime)s | %(message)s\n------------',
    datefmt='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S'
)

while True:
    try:
        bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
        user_dict = {}


        class User:
            def __init__(self, text):
                self.text = text


        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def text(message: Message):
            try:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
                bt1 = types.KeyboardButton('0')
                bt2 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
                bt3 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
                bt4 = types.KeyboardButton('3')
                bt5 = types.KeyboardButton('4')
                bt6 = types.KeyboardButton('5')
                bt7 = types.KeyboardButton('Отмена')
                markup.add(bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7)
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Выберите *число*', parse_mode='Markdown',
                                       reply_markup=markup)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_switch)

            except:
                logging.error('text', exc_info=True)


        def text_switch(message: Message):
            try:
                chat_id = message.chat.id
                user_dict[chat_id] = User(message.text)
                user = user_dict[chat_id]
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

                if message.text == '0':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '0️⃣ Ноль', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '1':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '1️⃣ Один', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '2':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '2️⃣ Два', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '3':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '3️⃣ Три', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '4':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '4️⃣ Четыре', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '5':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '5️⃣ Пять', reply_markup=markup)

                else:
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '⛔ Отмена', reply_markup=markup)

            except:
                logging.error('text_switch', exc_info=True)
                bot.send_message(chat_id, '❗ Какая-то *ошибка*!', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)

        bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)
        bot.load_next_step_handlers()
        bot.polling()

    except:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Однако для создания клавиатуры нужно много строк кода - одну под создание клавиатуры, под каждую кнопку и одну под добавление кнопок. К тому же очень надоедает в функцию добавления прописывать каждую кнопку через запятую. До этого момента меня не особо тревожило, однако сейчас мне это надоело, поэтому я написал **функцию создания клавиатуры**. Она представлена в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вход функция принимает список с названиями кнопок и количество кнопок в строке (по умолчанию 2)

**Сама функция:**

```
# Создание клавиатуры
def create_keyboard(keys: list, row_width: int = 2):
    keyboard= []
    for key in keys:
        keyboard.append(types.KeyboardButton(key))
    return types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, row_width=row_width).add(
        *keyboard)
```

**Использование в примере:**

```
import logging
import time

import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import Message

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='errors.txt',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='\n%(asctime)s | %(message)s\n------------',
    datefmt='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S'
)

while True:
    try:
        bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
        user_dict = {}


        class User:
            def __init__(self, text):
                self.text = text


        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def text(message: Message):
            try:
                markup = create_keyboard(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'Отмена'])
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Выберите *число*', parse_mode='Markdown',
                                       reply_markup=markup)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_switch)

            except:
                logging.error('text', exc_info=True)


        def text_switch(message: Message):
            try:
                chat_id = message.chat.id
                user_dict[chat_id] = User(message.text)
                user = user_dict[chat_id]
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

                if message.text == '0':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '0️⃣ Ноль', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '1':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '1️⃣ Один', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '2':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '2️⃣ Два', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '3':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '3️⃣ Три', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '4':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '4️⃣ Четыре', reply_markup=markup)

                elif message.text == '5':
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '5️⃣ Пять', reply_markup=markup)

                else:
                    bot.send_message(chat_id, '⛔ Отмена', reply_markup=markup)

            except:
                logging.error('text_switch', exc_info=True)
                bot.send_message(chat_id, '❗ Какая-то *ошибка*!', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)


        # Создание клавиатуры
        def create_keyboard(keys: list, row_width: int = 2):
            keyboard = []
            for key in keys:
                keyboard.append(types.KeyboardButton(key))
            return types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, row_width=row_width).add(
                *keyboard)


        bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)
        bot.load_next_step_handlers()
        bot.polling()

    except:
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Благодаря этой функции для создания каждой клавиатуры нужно прописать всего лишь 1 строку кода (не считая перенос, если очень длинная)